# Change Debug property of a Visual Studio project programmatically using EnvDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

Is it possible to change the Debug property of a project programmatically using EnvDTE classes? I know how to get the DTE instance, but I don't know how to change the value of this option. I need to change this property to be able to programmatically remove the vshost.exe file.

Screenshot of the option in question:

[image]

Comment: Try running [this code sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.properties.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2), with some luck it is included and you'll know the Property.Name.  Some odds for "UseVSHostingProcess" but you have to fret over the configuration.

Comment: Thank you, guy. It really works.

Comment: Badaboom!  Please close your question, tick the checkmark to the left of your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone will need the answer

```
Project proj = dte.Solution.Projects.Item(1);
Configuration config = proj.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;
config.Properties.Item("UseVSHostingProcess").Value = false;
```